# Can I scan a QrCode with the Android emulator without a Webcam?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, qr-code

I'm trying to understand the API zxing to develop my own barcode scanner by doing many tests. Right now I'm using an Android terminal, but it's not the best solution. So is there a solution to scan a QrCode with the Android Emulator and without a webcam? I imagined something like using an image placed into the SDCard.

(I'm using Eclipse with the Android SDK to develop this and I don't have a webcam.)

Comment: FWIW, I have a webcam connected to the emulator, and it still doesn't want to automatically detect a QR code.  So your stopgap solution of using an image on the SD card is probably just as good as a real solution...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers, but I haven't a webcam on my computer (I edited my question).

I found a solution which in which a picture (QrCode, FlashCode,...) is placed on the SD Card of the emulator. Unfortunately it works only with the release 1.3 of zxing.

So if anybody have an idea to do this with the last release, I would like to study it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a camera for scanning a QR code. Until now the emulator does not support taking pictures. If you can't get your hands on a test device with a camera testing QR code apps will be very hard.

Answer (score 1):

I found something online that lets you use your computer's webcam as the camera in the emulator. Give it a try. [Live Camera Previews in Android](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source)